# How can I install the youtube lens for Unity 20.04?

Tags: unity, software-installation, unity-dash

I am seeking to search YouTube via my unity dash, but I can't seem to find a way to install it. I have tried `sudo apt-get install lens-video scope-youtube` but it's not working. I am getting an error saying:

```
E: Unable to locate package lens-video
E: Unable to locate package scope-youtube
```

How can I remedy this?

[image: no release file]

[image: searching in Dash does not show YouTube videos]

[image: missing dependency]

[image: dependency on python-requests not satisfiable]

Comment: That package was actually provided by the atareao/lens ppa but it hasn't been updated since 2016.

Comment: Does [this](https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/exp/+files/scope-youtube_0.0.4.6-0~22~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb) .deb file work for you? If it does, I will write it into an answer

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no. it says the following package has unmet dependencies....

Comment: nevermind, i give up.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i will show you.i will update the question. see update 2.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi as you can see your package is made for ubuntu 18.04.1 and I am on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The version of Ubuntu should not be an issue. What is the missing dependency? Can you open the .deb file with gdebi (`sudo apt install gdebi`), and tell me what is the missing dependency?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i will show you what it says. see update 3 on the question.

Comment: anyways i dont think my dash will allow me to search the internet. there are already scopes installed as dash plugins on my dash and they don't work. i have  enabled ''allow search online sources'' in security and privacy  and the result is still nothing.

Comment: I see. It is looking for python2 dependencies. Looks like it has to be repackaged to work with python3. I don't know if the code is compatible with python3. If the same code works, I will make a new package and would let you know.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi , are you saying that i have to download python2 for it to work? because I can do this.

Comment: No, this package (python-requests, which is for python2) has been removed. Installing python2 won't help. Now there is `python3-requests`. However, I don't know if the code would work with python3. I would try to make a new package with a dependency of `python3-requests`, and it might work.

Comment: thank you. i don't know if it will be a waste of your time tho. because my unity dash seems to refuse to connect to the internet in any way

Comment: Instead of using Unity in Ubuntu, try this distro. https://ubuntuunity.org/ It is actively maintained (however, it is off topic on Ask Ubuntu, as it is not an official flavor).

Comment: i'm downloading it but i'm not sure I'll know how to install it.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi could you guide me on how to install it please when it's done downloading?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i've got a pendrive if needed be.

Comment: It's the same way you install Ubuntu. Download the iso, write it into a live USB drive, and boot from the live USB drive to run the installer. They also have a telegram support group. https://t.me/ubuntuunitydiscuss

Comment: another person did the first part for me. i only did the installation part. how do I write it into an USB drive? please tell me.

Comment: i dont use telegram

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi ok i'm reading up on how to do it. i think i will know how to do it.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi just a question : does my USB drive have to be empty? because there is ubuntu 20.04 written on it already.

Comment: You can format it and then flash the iso to the usb drive.

Comment: The package fails to build with python3. I don't know enough python to port it to python3